# Cannot run query: project does not have the reservation in the data region

Tags: google-bigquery

Since today, suddenly, I am constantly receiving the following error when tried to execute query jobs in Google Big Query:

> Cannot run query: project does not have the reservation in the data region

I tried with several projects and still this error persists. 
Has anyone ever encountered this error?

Comment: Everything working fine for me. Cloud status is normal too. Can you provide some job-ids for the BigQuery team? https://status.cloud.google.com/

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah sure. This ones for example failed just now: bi-category:bquijob_5da705b8_16174347bfa and another one from a differen project: ventures-1204:bquijob_7efad96_161743b2852

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Reservation" here refers to computing slots. You have slots for computation in one region (or none available at all), but data lies in another region.

Answer (score 0):

Your reservation has been configured on Feb 13th. Now the problem should have been fixed.